# How to compute (in non adaptative way based on MMSE FIR) the feedback and feedword filter for DFE equalization?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, digital-communications, kalman-filters

### System Model

Consider the single-input single-output (SISO) communication system in the figure below:

[image]
 where the information bit stream is encoded and mapped such that the output of the encoder is a sequence of encoded bits stream $\mathrm{c}=\left[\mathrm{c}_{1} \mathrm{c}_{2} \cdots \mathrm{c}_{\mathrm{N}}\right]$ where $\mathrm{c}_{\mathrm{k}}$ represents $\left[c_{k, 1} c_{k, 2} \cdots c_{k, q}\right]$ with bits $c_{k, j} \in\{0,1\}$
and $\mathrm{N}$ is the number of transmitted codewords and $q$ is the number of bits per symbol. The mapper uses a Gray code to map each bit vector $\mathbf{c}_{\mathrm{k}}$ to a symbol $x_{k}$ from the $2^{q}$ array constellation set $S=\left\{\alpha_{1} \alpha_{2} \cdots \alpha_{2} q\right\},$ where $\alpha_{i}$ corresponds to the deterministic bit pattern $\mathbf{s}_{k} = \left[s_{k, 1} s_{k, 2} \cdots s_{k, q}\right]$ with $s_{i, j} \in\{0,1\}$ which specifies the mapping between the encoded bits and the elements of the constellation.

Next, the generated symbols are modulated with a carrier and transmitted through the channel $h_{k} .$ At the receiver, the received baseband signal can be written as

\begin{equation}
y_{k}=\sum_{l= 0}^{l=L} h_{l} x_{k-l}+n_{k}
\end{equation}
here $h_{l}$ is the $l^{t h}$ tap of the channel and $L$ is the total length of the channel. In addition, $n_{k}$ represents an additive Gaussian white noise with zero mean and variance $\sigma_{n}^{2} .$ Arranging the previous equation into a matrix form we have

\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{y}_{k} &=\mathbf{H x}_{k}+\mathbf{n}_{k} \\
\mathbf{y}_{k} &=\left[y_{k}, y_{k-1} \cdots y_{k - K}\right]^{T} \\
\mathbf{x}_{k} &=\left[x_{k}, x_{k-1} \cdots x_{k-K-L}\right]^{T} \\
\mathbf{n}_{k} &=\left[n_{k}, n_{k-1} \cdots n_{k - K}\right]^{T} \\
\mathbf{H} &=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
h_{0} & \cdots & h_{L} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & h_{0} & \cdots & h_{L}
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}

The signal $y_{k}$ is input to the feedforward filter and the input of the feedback filter comes from the previously detected symbols. The output of the equalizer can be represented with the following equation.
\begin{equation}
\hat{x}_{k}=\sum_{j=0}^{K} w_{j} y_{k-j}+\sum_{j=1}^{K_{3}} d_{j} \tilde{x}_{k-j}
\end{equation}

where $\hat{x}_{k}$ and $\tilde{x}_{k-1}$ represent the estimated symbol and the previously detected symbol at time instance $k$ respectively. $\left\{w_{j}\right\}$ and $\left\{d_{j}\right\}$ represents the the tap coefficients of the feedforward and feedback filter respectively.Assuming we are computing the equalizer filter based on reference symbols.

\begin{aligned}
\hat{x}_{k} &=\mathbf{w} \mathbf{y}_{k}+\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}_{k}^{d} \\
\mathbf{x}_{k}^{d} &=\left[x_{k}, x_{k-1} \cdots x_{k-K_{3}}\right]^{T} \\
\mathbf{w} &=\left[w_{0,} w_{K-1}, \cdots w_{K}\right] \\
\mathbf{d} &=\left[d_{0}, d_{1}, \cdots d_{K_{3}}\right]
\end{aligned}

where $x_{k}^{d}$ is a vector contains the past $K_{3}$ decided symbols (or reference symbols) and $w$ and $d$ are feedforward and feedback coefficients at the time instance $k$ respectively.

I am looking for that analytical and non adaptative solution to implement it in matlab

### Matlab code : Help is needed here

```
function [dfseSNR,w_t,opt_delay]=dfsecolorsnr(l,p,nff,nbb,delay,Ex,noise);
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% [dfseSNR,w_t,opt_delay] = dfecolor(l,p,nff,nbb,delay,Ex,noise);
% l     = oversampling factor
% p     = pulse response, oversampled at l (size)
% nff   = number of feedforward taps
% nbb   = number of feedback taps 
% delay = delay of system <= nff+length of p - 2
%         if delay = -1, then choose best delay
% Ex    = average energy of signals
% noise = noise autocorrelation vector (size l*nff)
% NOTE: noise is assumed to be stationary
%
% outputs:
% dfseSNR = equalizer SNR, unbiased in dB
% w_t = equalizer coefficients [w -b]
% opt_delay = optimal delay found if delay =-1 option used.
%             otherwise, returns delay value passed to function
% created 4/96;
% ---------------------------------------------------------------

size = length(p);
nu = ceil(size/l)-1;
p = [p zeros(1,(nu+1)*l-size)];

% error checks
if nff<=0
  error('number of feedforward taps must be > 0');
end
if nbb<0
  error('number of feedback taps must be >= 0');
end
if delay > (nff+nu-1)
  error('delay must be <=  (nff+(length of p)-2)');
elseif delay < -1 
  error('delay must be >= -1');
elseif delay == -1
    delay = 0:1:nff+nu-1;
end

%form ptmp = [p_0 p_1 ... p_nu] where p_i=[p(i*l) p(i*l-1)... p((i-1)*l+1)
ptmp(1:l,1) = [p(1); zeros(l-1,1)];
for i=1:nu
  ptmp(1:l,i+1) = conj((p(i*l+1:-1:(i-1)*l+2))');
end

dfseSNR = -100;
%loop over all possible delays
for d = delay,
    %% COMPUTE EXACT number of feedback taps WE NEED to 
    %% consider given delay d
    nbb_used = min(nff+nu-1-d,nbb);
    %form matrix P, vector channel matrix
    P = zeros(nff*l+nbb_used,nff+nu);
    for i=1:nff,
        P(((i-1)*l+1):(i*l),i:(i+nu)) = ptmp;
    end
    P(nff*l+1:nff*l+nbb_used,d+2:d+1+nbb_used) = eye(nbb_used);
    %compute Rn matrix
    Rn  = zeros(nff*l+nbb_used);
    Rn(1:nff*l,1:nff*l) = toeplitz(noise);
    temp = zeros(1,nff+nu);
    temp(d+1)=1;
    %construct matrices
    Ry  = Ex*P*P' + Rn;
    Rxy = Ex*temp*P';
    new_w_t = Rxy*inv(Ry);
    sigma_dfse = Ex - real(new_w_t*Rxy');
    new_dfseSNR = 10*log10(Ex/sigma_dfse - 1);
    %save setting of this delay if best performance so far
    if new_dfseSNR >= dfseSNR
        w_t = new_w_t;
        dfseSNR = new_dfseSNR;
        opt_delay = d; 
        nbb_final = nbb_used;
    end
end

if nbb_final < nbb
    warning(strcat('For OPTIMAL FB filter settings N_bb=',num2str(nbb_final),' was used instead of the N_bb=',num2str(nbb), ' inputed'));
end

clearvars; close all; clc;

l = 1;                        %- oversampling factor
p = [ 0.807 0.215 0.207];     %- channel impulse resp
nff = 5 ;                     %- FeedForward Filter length 
nbb = 5;                      %- Feedback Filter length
delay = 1;                   %- allow to check for max delay
N = 1e2;                      %- Number of known sequence
SNR = 16;

MemFF = zeros(nff,1);         %- memory init of the feedforward filter input
MemBW = zeros(nbb,1);         %- memory init of the feedback filter input
hFF = zeros(nff,1);           %- FeedForward Filter
hFB = zeros(nbb,1);           %- Feedback Filter

s = randi([0 1],N,1);         
smod = qammod(s,2,'gray','InputType','bit'); 
x = filter(p, 1, smod);
xin = awgn(x, SNR, 'measured');   %- input signal to equalize

Ex = mean((abs(x.^2)));           %- inpput signal Energy 
SNRLinear = 10.^(SNR/10); 
sigma_square = Ex./SNRLinear;
out = zeros(N,1);
sdec = zeros(size(s));

%-
noise = [sigma_square, zeros(1,nff-1)]; %acf(xin-x,nff);               %- noise auto correlation
[dfseSNR,w_t,opt_delay] = dfsecolorsnr(l,p,nff,nbb,delay,Ex,noise);
hFF= w_t(1:nff);                   %- vector of coefficients for the feedforward FIR filter
hFB= w_t(nff+1:end);               %- vector of coefficients for the feedforward FIR filter

%- DFE Equalization loop block 
%- I need to fine tune this loop 
for n = 1: length(xin)
    MemFF = [xin(n); MemFF(1:nff-1)];
    out(n) = hFF*MemFF + hFB*MemBW; 
    sdec(n) = qamdemod(out(n),2,'gray','OutputType','bit');
    MemBW = [sdec(n); MemBW(1:nbb-1)];
end

error_num = sum(sdec~= s);
```